# Como resolver esta consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Listar el nombre de los clientes que hayan viajado en todos los autos.**

*Tengo 4 tablas, auto, chófer, cliente y viaje, la única con foreing key es viaje que adquiere las primarias de chófer, cliente y viaje*

*Asi es como lo hice pero me da mal:*

```
SELECT nombre
FROM cliente 
INNER JOIN viaje on cliente.nro_cliente = viaje.nro_cliente
INNER JOIN auto on viaje.patente = auto.patente
GROUP BY cliente.nombre
HAVING avg(viaje.patente) = avg(auto.patente);
```

Ó

```
SELECT nombre
FROM cliente 
INNER JOIN viaje on cliente.nro_cliente = viaje.nro_cliente
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT patente
FROM auto
WHERE auto.patente = viaje.patente
);
```

AQUÍ LAS TABLAS

```
create table auto
(
patente varchar(50),
modelo varchar(50),
año int,
primary key (patente)
);

create table chofer
(
nombre varchar(50),
telefono int,
nro_chofer int,
fecha_ingreso varchar(50),
primary key (nro_chofer)
);

create table cliente
(
nombre varchar(50),
domicilio varchar(50),
nro_cliente int,
localidad varchar(50),
primary key (nro_cliente)
);

create table viaje
(
patente varchar(50),
nro_chofer int,
nro_cliente int,
fecha varchar(50),
km_totales int,
tiempo_espera varchar(50),
primary key (nro_cliente, nro_chofer, patente, fecha),
foreign key (nro_cliente) references cliente (nro_cliente),
foreign key (nro_chofer) references chofer (nro_chofer),
foreign key (patente) references auto (patente)
);
```

Comment: si pones las estructuras de las tablas, de seguro sera mucho mas facil entender y ayudarte.... ya que asi se podran ver lo campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas los clientes que hubieran alquilado todos los autos, lo cual te requiere determinar dos datos fundamentales

- La cantidad total de autos que tienes registrados
- La cantidad de autos distintos que ha alquilado cada cliente

Sabiendo esto, simplemente debes ver aquellos clientes en que coincidan ambos números:

```
SELECT  nombre
        FROM cliente c
        -- Cantidad de autos distintos x cliente
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  nro_cliente,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT patente) AS 'CantAutos'
                            FROM viaje  
                            GROUP BY nro_cliente
              ) v
              ON v.nro_cliente = c.nrocliente
        -- Cantidada total de autos.
        WHERE v.CantaAutos = (SELECT COUNT(patente) FROM auto)
```

Answer (score 1):

También se puede hacer con `HAVING` del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
    c.nombre
FROM viajes v 
    INNER JOIN  auto    a  ON v.patente     = a.patente 
    INNER JOIN  cliente c  ON v.nro_cliente = c.nro_cliente 
GROUP BY  c.nro_cliente 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.patente) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auto);
```

Y, si quieres mostrar el total de autos:

```
SELECT 
    c.nombre, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.patente) total_autos
FROM viajes v 
    INNER JOIN  auto    a  ON v.patente     = a.patente 
    INNER JOIN  cliente c  ON v.nro_cliente = c.nro_cliente 
GROUP BY  c.nro_cliente 
HAVING total_autos = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auto);
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi con los querys siempre me funciona pensar como si lo estuviera haciendo a mano.

Primero consultaría cuantos autos tenemos (en realidad en el query de ejemplo lo pongo en el having)

Luego consultaría la tabla de viajes.
Sobre esa buscaría el total de viajes realizados por cada cliente donde los autos son distintos.

Volvería a consultar sobre este conjunto y agruparía por cliente poniendo como condición al agrupado que el total resultante sea igual al total de autos.

Lo que resulte lo entendería como el resultado cruzando con la tabla de cliente para obtener el nombre:

```
WITH TT_VEHICULOS_CLIENTE_DIST AS (
   SELECT NRO_CLIENTE
        , PATENTE        
     FROM VIAJE
 GROUP BY NRO_CLIENTE
        , PATENTE
)  SELECT c.NRO_CLIENTE
        , c.NOMBRE
     FROM TT_VEHICULOS_CLIENTE_DIST t
     JOIN CLIENTE c
       ON c.NRO_CLIENTE = t.NRO_CLIENTE
 GROUP BY c.NRO_CLIENTE
        , c.NOMBRE
   HAVING COUNT(*) =  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTO)
```

Por supuesto el **WITH** puede sustituirse por una subconsulta pero al menos a mi se me hace más claro ponerlo de esta manera.